# Microsoft Azure - policy to prevent creation of resources not covered by MSDN credit

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm trying to create an Azure policy which would deny creation of any resource that's not covered by my MSDN subscription 130€ monthly quota. What happens is that I inadvertently create a resource which is not covered by MSDN subscription monthly quota, which leads to my Azure subscription being disabled the next day, and it remains disabled until the end of the monthly billing cycle. I raised a support issue with Microsoft, but they refused to help (because they are tring to get customers credit card data, which would remove the spending limit, and that's something I don't want to do).

Answer (score 0):

Azure policy is not design to enforce billing quotas billing, it more for setting guidelines/policies about what can be deployed in subscriptions in your tenant.

MSDN account will cap at a certain amount, you can keep use the 'budgets' option on the subscription to keep track of how much you are spending.

Most 'enterprise' cloud providers are Pay-As-You-Go so no one is going to guarantee you a fixed price.  You can also use the [Azure Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to get an idea of what setup and consumption will let you stay under the MSDN quota.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm not trying to enforce a billing quota, I'm trying to prevent deploying resources whose billing is not included in my quota, which is a different thing. For example, if I deploy a Windows VM, it will generate some expanses which will be deducted from my monthyly quota. But if I deploy an automation watcher, it will generate expanses *not* included in my quota, and consequently disable the account until the end of the billing cycle (month).

Comment: I understood you before but the new comment is what is confusing.  I have used MSDN subscription for years, the only time it is disabled is when you have used up all your quota.  So if your account is getting disable is not because of something not included in quota.  You cannot deploy 3rd party stuff not included in quota without credit card on account.

Comment: You definitively can deploy 3rd party stuff not included in quota, without a credit card on account! It happened to me several times as I was following Microsoft tutorials. For example, you can create a Red Hat server, and if you have a MSDN subscription, it'll get disabled the next day. My newest misfortune is that I created an automation account (that's fine), and then a watcher for that account (it has caused my subscription to be disabled). Microsoft is unwilling to provide any kind of comprehensive list of what is charged as part of the quota and what is not, therefore the question.

Comment: When you are deploying 3rd party billing stuff you should have information like this https://i.imgur.com/fucVAv7.png letting you know its not part of your credit and it will not allow you to deploy without credit card on file.  Things mentioned, Automation account and watcher for account (https://i.imgur.com/0rfQeiV.png) are not 3rd party.  You need to file a billing ticket to really understand why the account is getting disabled if you have MSDN credit and also check if there is any External services enable on subscription (https://i.imgur.com/EZNhbTd.png)

Comment: I've had my subscription disabled several times, filed tickets with MS each and every time, and the subscription was always disabled because I inadvertently created or activated resources which were not covered by my MSDN subscription credit. This last time, it was the automation watcher that caused the subscription to be disabled. The mail from MS: "I downloaded the usage report and I observed that you are using a service named Watcher , this is the reason for CAP reach. "

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense. 'Watcher' is maxing out your credit causing account to be disabled, but I believe they are talking about network watcher and not the  watcher task on automation account. Even if there was a policy to block 3rd party deployment this wouldn't be covered.

Comment: @Marko Reach out to me directly if you need additional help narrowing down issue.

Comment: Not, it's automation watcher. What follows is an excerpt from the billing XLS, it's chaotic but you can see that the cause of the problem is a charge of only 0,01EUR. (3rd data from the end) =>

Comment: Billing period Meter Category Meter Id Meter Sub-category Meter Name Meter_Region SKU Consumed Quantity Included Quantity Overage Quantity Commitment Quantity List Price Commitment Price Consumption Price Commitment Discount Consumption Discount Monetary Credit Amount Pre-Tax Charges Tax Amount Post-Tax Total Currency Pre-Tax Effective Rate Post-Tax Effective Rate
201904: 3/23/2019 ~ 4/22/2019 Automation 0fb93388-dbb5-46ec-ba5f-bde2b8da0891 Process Watcher  9YD-00001 3 0 3 0 0,001686 0 0,003333333 0 0 0 0,01 0 0,01 EUR 0,003333333 0,003333333

Comment: It can't be on this forum, Azure Policy is not design for that.  Billing are private issue if you need assistance we can take it offline. email me.